# Como Executar função IF ao selecionar item do ComboBox?

Tags: c#

Eu queria saber como fazer um `if` funcionar apenas quando a `combobox` tiver algum item selecionado.
Estou a fazer um  programa em  windows forms e preciso de um `if` para limitar o programa a só fazer aquela função quando a `combobox` conter algo selecionado.
Este é o código que eu tenho de limitar:

```
 if () {
    var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + comboBox1.SelectedText + "$]", conexao);
    var ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds, comboBox1.SelectedText + "$");
    DataTable data = ds.Tables[comboBox1.SelectedText + "$"];

    foreach (DataColumn dc in data.Columns)
    {
         comboBox2.Items.Add(dc.ColumnName);
         comboBox3.Items.Add(dc.ColumnName);
         comboBox4.Items.Add(dc.ColumnName);
         comboBox5.Items.Add(dc.ColumnName);
    }
 }
```

Eu preencho a combobox1 com este código:

```
using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xls", ValidateNames = true })
            {
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    FileStream fs = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fs);
                    reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
                    result = reader.AsDataSet();
                    comboBox1.Items.Clear();

                    foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables) comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
                    reader.Close();

                    string ConecçãoDB = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConecçaoDB"].ConnectionString;
                    string Table = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["table"];

                    string ssqltable = Table;

                    string ssqlconnectionstring = ConecçãoDB;

                    filename = ofd.FileName;
                     MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(filename));
                    var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";

                    var conexao = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString);

                    var sql = "SELECT * FROM [PARAC1$]";
                    string sclearsql = "delete from " + ssqltable;
}
}
```

Comment: Pergunta muito ampla, vaga é Web é Forms é em qual deles? falta dar uma contextualizada e colocar mais informações .

Comment: @VirgilioNovic já actualizei a minha pergunta , peço desculpa .

Comment: Coloque o código atual! também isso ajuda a clarear mais ...

Comment: comboBox1.SelectedText  tem o nome de planilhas?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Sim ,tem .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (comboBox1.Items.Count > 0) comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0; // posiciona no primeiro item
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox1.Text) == false) 
{
    var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" 
                         + comboBox1.Text+ "$]", conexao);
    var ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds, comboBox1.Text+ "$");
    DataTable data = ds.Tables[comboBox1.Text + "$"];

    foreach (DataColumn dc in data.Columns)
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Add(dc.ColumnName);
        comboBox3.Items.Add(dc.ColumnName);
        comboBox4.Items.Add(dc.ColumnName);
        comboBox5.Items.Add(dc.ColumnName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Não sei porque mas assim não escreve nas outras combobox os nomes das colunas

Comment: Se já debugou o código @PedroAzevedo ??? com breakpoint?

Comment: Sim , simplesmente não faz nada

Comment: fiz uma edição @PedroAzevedo é `Text` dá uma olhada!

Comment: Não faz nada tentei meter no código uma message box e nem isso aparece

Comment: Como você o preenche @PedroAzevedo coloque na sua pergunta.

Comment: Como preencho o que ?

Comment: Como você carrega as informações para `comboBox1` ???

Comment: Já actualizei .

Comment: @PedroAzevedo você atualizou do jeito que eu fiz na resposta?

Comment: Sim mesmo assim não funcionou

Comment: Deve ser um problema local de dificil reprodução, você sabe se ele entra nesse `if()` utilizando breakpoint e F11 ???

Comment: Ele passa o if, não chega a entrar

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66993/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-pedro-azevedo).

Answer (score 3):

Você quer executar determinada função quando algum item do seu **ComboBox** for selecionada certo?

No evento **SelectedIndexChanged** do ComboBox é possível executar tal ação, veja.

```
private void meuComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
   if (meuComboBox.SelectedIndex >= 0)
      //Executa sua função "if" aqui
   }
```